# Domain model issue with objects with multiple properties. How should I structure it?

Tags: java, domain-model, color-space

I am making a tiny game app in my free time, and I have just recently hit a wall.

The idea is that there is a fixed grid of `Box`es available and that many `Jewel`s as well.

Both boxes and jewels can come in different colors. As with color space, the three basic type of boxes are Red, Yellow and Blue. The other ones available are, of course, Orange, Purple, Green, with a special White box.

I also have the Jewels, which correspond to the same colors as boxes.

Now, the logic is as following:

- Primary color boxes will give reward only if they contain a gem whose color is the same as the box color or is made from the box color

  - For example, red box will give bonus if there is a red, orange or purple jewel inside it because of the following

    - Red is made of Red
    - Orange is made of Red and Yellow
    - Purple is made of Red and Blue
    - White is made of Red, Blue and Yellow
  - Red box won't give any bonus for Green jewel, because Green is Blue and Yellow and there is no Red in there
- Secondary color boxes cannot accept any of the primary color jewels because secondary color boxes are made of at least two colors, while primary gems are made of 1 color only.

  - Given that, secondary color boxes can only accept the corresponding color jewel, plus the white one.
- And as an exception to the rules above, white box is like a bonus box, which can accept all jewels

I'm puzzled with how to make the domain model for this so it doesn't contain (or contains as least as possible) `if`s and `instanceof`s.

Also, if I would like to extend the types of boxes and jewels one day, I'd like it to be done in any of the following two ways by adding new classes without having to change old ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine you could have something like this:

```
public enum Color {

    RED(true),
    YELLOW(true),
    BLUE(true),
    ORANGE(false),
    PURPLE(false),
    GREEN(false),
    WHITE(false);

    static {
        ORANGE.components.add(RED);
        ORANGE.components.add(YELLOW);

        PURPLE.components.add(RED);
        PURPLE.components.add(BLUE);

        GREEN.components.add(YELLOW);
        GREEN.components.add(BLUE);

        WHITE.components.add(RED);
        WHITE.components.add(YELLOW);
        WHITE.components.add(BLUE);    
    }

    private boolean primary;
    private List<Color> components;

    Color(boolean primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
        this.components = new ArrayList<Color>();
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public Set<Color> components() {
         return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.components);
    }
}
```

Then you can have something like this:

```
public class Jewel {
    private Color color;

    ...
}

public class Box {
    private Color color;
    private Jewel jewel;

    ...
}
```

All the score calculation can be done inside a scoring service of some kind:

```
public class ScoringService {

    public int calculate(Box box) {
        int score = 0;
        Jewel jewel = box.getJewel();

        if(box.getColor() == jewel.getColor() || box.getColor() == Color.WHITE) {
            score++;
        }

        if(!box.getColor().isPrimary() && jewel.getColor() == Color.WHITE) {
            score++;
        }    

        if(box.getColor().isPrimary() && !jewel.getColor().isPrimary()) {
            Set<Color> intersection = new HashSet<Color>(box.getColor().components());
intersection.retainAll(jewel.getColor().components());
            score += intersection.size();
        }

        return score;
    }
}
```

Comment: It is a good start, however, what if (in some universe where there are more primary colors) I wish to add another primary color? I would have to change `Color` enum.

My initial thoughts were revolving around interfaces that would represent colors, like `class PurpleJewel implements ColorableRed, ColorableBlue`, but that kind of thinking got me nowhere. In any case, upvoted for the effort, will see if any has any other train of thought on this before I accept the answer :)

Comment: @Lopina It's far more preferable to add values to the `Color` `enum` instead of having individual `Jewel` classes based on the color :). That can quickly lead to class explosion and is not a good design. If you want this to be more extensible, you can use a property file that contains colors and their components, and then read that in and populate a `Color` class (not an enum in this case). However you lose the ability to refer to colors individually in a type-safe manner.